# Как правильно построить предложение: "Создать новый мир с расширенными параметрами"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, переводы

Я занимаюсь переводом одной игры с английского, в ней есть пункт меню, который я перевел как:

> ***"Создать новый мир с расширенными параметрами"***

в оригинале:

> *"Design New World with Advanced Parameters"*

Так вот, один товарищ говорит мне, что предложение построено неверно, но в чем ошибка не признается :)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это предложение построить более правильно с точки зрения русского языка?

Comment: Уж не dwarf fortress ли вы переводите?

Answer (score 2):

Я согласна с @insolor что "with Advanced Parameters" относится к созданию, а не к миру. Но как это выразить?
Мои предложения:

> Создать новый мир (для продвинутого/опытного пользователя)
>   Создать новый мир (для продвинутых)
>   Создать новый мир (расширенная параметризация)

Comment: Третий вариант - да. Первые два- точно нет, не о пользователе речь.

Answer (score 1):

А реально-то что в игре означает advanced? Глагол многозначный, как и почти всё в английском. Здесь, возможно, речь идёт о "продвинутой" параметризации, т.е. включении в список параметров дополнительных. Как это по-русски сказать кратко - не знаю пока.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет именно о "мире с раширенными параментрами", то, по-моему, все написано верно.

Comment: Скорее не "мир с расширенными параметрами", а "создание с расширенными параметрами". Речь идет о том, что будет доступно изменение дополнительных параметров, которые при "стандартном" создании игрового мира не показываются, а имеют какое-то значение по-умолчанию. Наверное правильнее было бы "Создание мира с использованием расширенных параметров", но очень уж длинно.

Answer (score 0):

Если идет речь о том, что можно большее число параметров мира задается не по умолчанию, а по выбору игрока, то есть два варианта.

1. Расширенное создание нового мира.
2. Детальное создание нового мира.

Comment: Не **создание**, а **создать**. Как в вопросе.

Comment: Геймеру без разницы "создать" или "создание" в меню - всё равно понятно. А "расширенно создать" не по-русски. А переводчик должен передать смысл, а не форму фразы, а в меню еще надо и уложиться в ограниченный объём.

Comment: insolor давно передал, и ему тоже всё равно уж лет десять как.

Answer (score 0):

Если мы хотим формально отнести атрибутивное обстоятельство или определение (с расширенными параметрами) соответственно к глаголу или существительному (создать мир), то можно воспользоваться вариативностью падежного примыкания у глагола *создать* или у существительного *мир*:

```
//отнесение к глаголу
Создать мир с учетом расширенных параметров 
Создать мир на основании расширенных параметров 
Создать мир, учитывая расширенные параметры 
//отнесение к существительному
Создать мир, включающий/имеющий расширенные параметры
```